# Line intersecting circle from origin

Tags: geometry

I have a basic question. FYI, I tried the line circle intersect formula but it seemed too complicated for this application.

Changed Image[Replaced Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeTi4.png)

Comment: There is no example listed.

Comment: Tags should perhaps be geometry and/or trigonometry.  This isn't linear algebra.

Comment: I think I have fixed the link. First post.

Comment: Thanks. I changed to geometry

Comment: We don't have enough information.  We need to have one of the rays of the angle specified.  Usually the base ray is assumed to be the $x$-axis so the point would be $(radius*\cos Angle, radius*\sin Angle)$.  But that is not clear by the picture.  Are we supposed to assume the left ray is the $y$ axis?

Comment: The line intersection formula would work fine (but is unnecessary) but you need to find the slope of the line based on the angle.  You will need the trig definitions for that.  (Although the trig definitions to find the slope will more or less give you the point).

Comment: @fleablood. Thanks also to the other contributors who also answered. I used you formula and it works for what I need.
Yes the start ray is always y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$O_x+R\sin\theta,O_y+R\cos\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to have anything to do with "a line intersecting a circle"!

You have a circle with center at the origin and radius R so its equation in this coordinate system is $x^2+ y^2= R^2$.  You then have a radius at angle $\theta$ to the y-axis. Together with the y-axis and the horizontal line from the terminal point of the radius on the circle, we have a right triangle with hypotenuse of length R and angle $\theta$.  The "opposite side" of that right triangle has length $R sin(\theta)$ and the "near side" has length $R cos(\theta)$.

The terminal point of the radius on the circle has coordinates $(R sin(\theta), R cos(\theta))$.

Notice that this has "cosine" and "sine" reversed from the formulas for "polar coordinates".  That is because polar coordinates measures $\theta$ from the x-axis, not the y-axis.

Comment: "This doesn't appear to have anything to do with "a line intersecting a circle"!"  Well, it *does*... the the ray of the angle intersects the circle.  If the OP was utterly wedded to the line intersection formula (whatever that is) s/he could figure the slope of the ray is $\frac {\sin a}{\cos a}$ and the ray is $y=\frac {\sin a}{\cos a}x$ and so solve  $x^2 + (\frac {\sin a}{\cos a}x)^2=R^2$.  Of course that's, err, circular because to know the slope of the ray you have to figure the point of the circle first.  ...Well, unit circle.

Comment: ..... assuming the left ray *is* the $y$-axis which is never explicitly stated.

Comment: I apologize for not being precise. Let me ask the question another way.

Comment: I apologize for not being precise. Let me ask the question another way.
What I am trying to do is track the coordinates along an arc, always 90 degrees. The are is always 1/4 of a circle. The circle radius is 50. I would like to calc the point along the arc and 1/4 distance, 1/2 and 3/4. I can make the arc direction always clockwise.

I have an image but I don't know how to add it to a comment.

Comment: I update the example on the original post